# How to solve this One-hot encoding error " all input arrays must have the same shape"

Tags: java, c#, php

Error I got is below..

all input arrays must have the same shape

Comment: The issue is mostly because one or more of your sequence in the `input_features` list is not of the same size as the others. And when you are stacking it to a numpy array, it is throwing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not striping lines. A normal DNA sequence is consist of A, G, C and T. You also consider `\r` character. Your input is like this:

```
CCGAGGGCTATGGTTTGGAAGTTAGAACCCTGGGGCTTCTCGCGGACACC\r
GAGTTTATATGGCGCGAGCCTAGTGGTTTTTGTACTTGTTTGTCGCGTCG\r
...
AATGTCGACCGAACTCCGCACTGCTGGCCCGGGCCTATATCGAGAGTGAC
```

So, for the lines except the last line, the encoder produces an array with the shape (50,5), because there are 5 different characters in the line. For the last line, it produces an array with the shape (50,4), then you got `ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape`.

To fix this, you can strip the sequences at somewhere in the code. For example, this would work:

```
...

for sequence in sequences:
  integer_encoded = integer_encoder.fit_transform(list(sequence.strip()))
...
```

**EDIT:**
Also, for the lines which are not using all for of A, G, C and T, you can skip the line:

```
...
for sequence in sequences:
  sequence_list = list(sequence.strip())
  if len(set(sequence_list)) != 4:
    continue
  integer_encoded = integer_encoder.fit_transform(sequence_list)
...
```

Or, you can find another way to make all of the `one_hot_encoded` arrays' shapes (50,4).

Comment: thanks...,oh my younger bro edit this mistakenly..how to revert changes??

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot undo an edit, but you can edit your question by updating the same question with same details. You can see the edit history by clicking [edited 17 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58678974/revisions) under your question, maybe you can undo your own change. Also, please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: this link is also not working...@Alperen  " https://genomics004.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Sequence.txt"

Comment: There is a line `ATATTCAATTTCATACATATTATTTTAAAATTTATAATCTTATATACTAC` in that link, and there is no G in it. So, encoder returns an array with the shape (50,3).

Comment: how you find it ?? @Alperen

Comment: By debugging with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Still not working @Alperen   I have change it ..https://genomics004.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Sequence.txt

Comment: Similar problem. You can see it with debugging. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: Updated my answer with a simple solution, but you can find another solution if don't want to lose any data.

Comment: But after changing the line "ATATTCAATTTCATACATATTATTTTAAAATTTATAATCTTATATACTAC"    into "ATATTCAATTTCATACATATTATTTTAAAATTTATAATCTTATATACTAG"  still problem exist..

Comment: Maybe another line has the same problem. Ignoring the line `if len(set(sequence_list)) != 4:` is working.

Comment: i cant get your point @Alperen , where to put this code" if len(set(sequence_list)) != 4:"

Comment: Can't get it , what are you trying to do

Comment: If the number of different characters in the sequence is not 4, the `one_hot_encoded` will not have 4 elements. So, some rows of the `input_features` will be like `[1,0,0]` or maybe `[0,1]`, then you will get `ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape` when running `np.stack(input_features)`

Comment: Can i get your email address...!!

Comment: I can't see details when you say that your code is not working. Writing comments will not be helpful to you. You can ask another proper question as described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Dear @Alperen  when i run code then it shows below error ...                                                                        
                                                                                                                                      Error is                                                                                                                              A target array with shape (337, 3) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Comment: How can I find the short motifs that is binding site in the sequence ...